# Using pen to control scrollviewer and disable touch

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, scrollviewer

For a page with a scrollviewer - using the hand gesture allows the user to scroll up and down and across or whatever.  Using a pen doesn't do anything. 
The requirement is to have a button to reverse the functionality of pen and touch.
If this button is pushed the touch can draw ink strokes on a canvas and the pen cannot.  This works.

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed with the situations:

- pen to be "gesture" to scroll page instead of touch.
- hand to draw ink stroke on a canvas that is within a scrollviewer.

Is there a method or attribute that i can set that makes the pen/hand accept gestures?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a suggestion (can't remember where) ... that i should disable the zooming and scrolling. When that was set I called the method to allow for inking. Not entirely sure if that's the correct way of doing it but through various testing...it worked.